# Indexing with nested vectors in APL

Tags: indexing, apl

I have a vector of vectors that contain some indices, and a character vector which I want to use them on.

```
A←(1 2 3)(3 2 1)
B←'ABC'
```

I have tried:

```
      B[A]
RANK ERROR
      B[A]
       ∧
```

```
      A⌷B
LENGTH ERROR
      A⌷B
       ∧
```

and

```
      A⌷B
LENGTH ERROR
      A⌷¨B
       ∧
```

I would like

```
┌→────────────┐
│ ┌→──┐ ┌→──┐ │
│ │ABC│ │CBA│ │
│ └───┘ └───┘ │
└∊────────────┘
```

to be returned, but if i need to find another way, let me know.

Comment: Could you specify which APL dialect and version you're using?

Comment: You might want to read the APL Orchard transcript starting from [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54626108#54626108), we discussed this question a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [index function](https://aplwiki.com/wiki/Index_(function)) `⌷` is a bit odd. To select multiple [major cells](https://aplwiki.com/wiki/Major_cell) from an array, you need to enclose the array of indices:

```
      (⊂3 2 1)⌷'ABC'
CBA
```

In order to use each of two vectors of indices, the array you're selecting from needs to be distributed among the two. You can use APL's scalar extension for this, but then the array you're selecting from needs to be packaged as a scalar:

```
      (⊂1 2 3)(⊂3 2 1)⌷¨⊂'ABC'
┌→────────────┐
│ ┌→──┐ ┌→──┐ │
│ │ABC│ │CBA│ │
│ └───┘ └───┘ │
└∊────────────┘
```

So to use your variables:

```
      A←(1 2 3)(3 2 1)
      B←'ABC'
      (⊂¨A)⌷¨⊂B
┌→────────────┐
│ ┌→──┐ ┌→──┐ │
│ │ABC│ │CBA│ │
│ └───┘ └───┘ │
└∊────────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that, if you are generating permutations which all have the same length, you may be better off avoiding nested arrays. Nested arrays force the system to follow pointers, while simple arrays allow sequential access to densely packed data. This only really matters when you have a LOT of data, of course:

```
      ⎕←SIMPLE←↑A ⍝ A 2×3 matrix of indices
1 2 3
3 2 1
      (⊂SIMPLE)⌷B
ABC
CBA
      B[SIMPLE] ⍝ IMHO bracket indexing is nicer for this
ABC
CBA
      ↓B[SIMPLE] ⍝ Split if you must
┌───┬───┐
│ABC│CBA│
└───┴───┘
```

Answer (score 0):

In NARS2000, easy:

```
  A←(1 3 2)(3 2 1)
  B←'ABC'
  ⎕fmt {B[⍵]}¨¨A
┌2────────────┐
│┌3───┐ ┌3───┐│
││ ACB│ │ CBA││
│└────┘ └────┘2
└∊────────────┘
  C←(1 3 2 3 2 1)(3 2 1) 
  ⎕fmt {B[⍵]}¨¨C
┌2───────────────┐
│┌6──────┐ ┌3───┐│
││ ACBCBA│ │ CBA││
│└───────┘ └────┘2
└∊───────────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m surprised that no one suggested

```
      A⊂⍤⌷⍤0 1⊢B
┌→────────────┐
│ ┌→──┐ ┌→──┐ │
│ │ABC│ │CBA│ │
│ └───┘ └───┘ │
└∊────────────┘
```

which says “pair each scalar (rank-0 array) of A with the corresponding vector (rank-1 array) of B; between each pair, use Index and box the result (of that individual pairing).”

Here B itself is a single vector, so B gets paired with each scalar from A. It’s relevant here to know that a box is a scalar in APL. (For the sake of clarity, `(1 2 3)(3 2 1)` creates two boxes.) You can use a right rank of 99 instead of 1 for a version that selects the major cells from an array B of arbitrary rank. The `⊢` just separates `B` from the ranks `0 1` so that `0 1 B` doesn't get treated as a single array of ranks.

With this expression there is no unnecessary boxing nor unboxing going on.

Some APL’ers prefer to use a modified Index function sometimes called Select or “sane indexing” that has reversed control semantics relative to `⌷`—in this version, each simple scalar in the left argument specifies a major cell, while each boxed vector specifies a single multidimensional index. Then we can use the “each-left” idiom `f¨∘⊂`:

```
      sel←{⊃⍺)⌷⍵}⍤0 99   ⍝ Extended Dyalog APL's ⊇
      A sel¨⊂B           ⍝ select each-left 
┌→────────────┐
│ ┌→──┐ ┌→──┐ │
│ │ABC│ │CBA│ │
│ └───┘ └───┘ │
└∊────────────┘
```